# Getting different local-port value in tcpdump when using --local-port option in curl

Tags: curl, tcpdump

I'm using `curl` command to send the traffic to the Server. In `curl` command, I'm using `--local-port` option. Below is the command:

```
curl -v --interface 10.1.1.3 -b --local-port 10000 http://30.1.1.101/myfile.txt
```

I'm taking `tcpdump` to confirm that whether the `local-port` is used or not. Below is the `tcpdump` stats(image):

[**tcpdump stats**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyPAS.jpg)

[image: tcpdump stats]

After checking the `tcpdump`, I have observed that the `local-port` value is different in `tcpdump`. It is supposed to be like `10.1.1.1:10000` not like `10.1.1.1:random_val`.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to force `curl` to use the same `local-port` that I have mentioned in the command?
2. What's the reason for getting different `local-port` value?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any Solution for above problem?

Comment: According [`man curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) as of v7.15.2 it should be possible via `--local-port` to "*Set a preferred single number or range (FROM-TO) of local port numbers to use for the connection(s).*". In a short test on my system it was working as long as port was free.

Comment: In your case, if the port were not free "*If you ask for a local port number (or range) that curl can't obtain for you, it will exit with a failure.*", according [Using curl - Connections](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl-connections.html) and which wasn't the case according your description. However, can you try with a port range?